# Please check this warning

Tags: warnings

This line is showing warning:

- Line is: `\textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE}`
- Warning is:

  > You have requested, on input line 164, version '2012/05/28' of package hobsub-generic, but only version '2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)' is available.

[image]

Code is here:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}

%usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\colorlet{white}{white}
\mode<presentation>
% 

%
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred!80!white}
%
%\usetheme{Singapore}
% \usetheme{Boadilla}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{BeamerColor}
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\The new themes are Warsaw, Boadilla, AnnArbor,Rochester,Antibes,JuanLesPins,Berlin,rounded,crane
%\usetheme[]{Szeged}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme[hoptionsi]{Berkeley}
%\usecolortheme[]{wolverine}
%\usetheme[]{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{dresden}
%\usefonttheme{structureitalicserif}
\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usetheme[]{}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=Brown]{structure}
%\usecolortheme[named=OliveGreen]{structure}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}
%\usecolortheme{oily}
%\setbeamerfont{}{size={50cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[ams style]
\usepackage{ragged2e}\justifying
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{epsf}
%\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{cor}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Algorithm}[theorem]{Algorithm}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\newcommand{\Date}{3 october 2019}% change the date here
\newcommand{\companyName}{Company Name Here} % change company name here
\newcommand{\Speaker}{Speaker} %change speaker name with 'speaker'
\newcommand{\SpeakerTitle}{Speaker's Title} %change speaker title with "Speaker's Title"
\title[company name]
{\LARGE \textbf{company name}}

\subtitle{}

\author[ABCD]{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.25,0.00}{ABCD}}

\institute[]
{\inst{}%
    ABC Uni

}
%
\date[]{ }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{split}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\pagestyle{plain}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}
%  \titlepage
%\end{frame} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 2 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
\begin{frame}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

    \vspace*{-0.5in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
        \vspace{-0.8cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
            {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
            {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.7cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
            {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}


    \restoregeometry
    %\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
    %spans two lines just under the logo}} 
    %\vfill
    \begin{columns}%beamer
        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        % blank
        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =2cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=white, width = 4.5cm]
                \textcolor{white}{\textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE}}
            \end{tcolorbox}
            \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
        \end{flushleft}

    \end{columns}
    %\section{1}
    %\textcolor{white}{click to add title}
\end{frame}

%\egroup
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 3 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page

    \section{Open Ball, Closed Ball, Sphere}\label{1114}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \vbox{
            \begin{minipage}[t][0.0025\textheight][t]{\textwidth}
                \tiny{\companyName $ |$ \Date}
            \end{minipage}\\

            \begin{minipage}[b][0.15\textheight][b]{0.95\textwidth}
                \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, top =0.1cm, bottom = 0.5cm, left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
                    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{minipage}\\

            \begin{minipage}[t][0.5\textheight][t]{0.95\textwidth}
                \begin{tcolorbox}[standard jigsaw, opacityback = 0, bottom =1.89in , left = 0 cm, colframe=black]
                    \textbf{CLICK TO ADD TITLE} 
                     %Edit this if you just want to change the text, else if you want to remove complete box then delete the block of "tcolorbox" and start writting required text
                \end{tcolorbox}
            \end{minipage}
            \begin{picture}(15, 33)(-293, -215)
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{3.png}
            \end{picture}
        }
    \end{flushleft}

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FRAME 4 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{1.png}} 
\begin{frame}
    \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \fill[green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(\paperwidth,0.27cm); %Draw green line at the bottom of the page
    \vspace*{-1in} %adjust this if your logo is being cropped from top
    \begin{flushleft}
        {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{2.png}}
        \vspace{-0.75cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
            {\textcolor{white}{A tagline for the company spans}}\\
            {\textcolor{white}{two lines just under the logo.}} \\
        \end{flushright}
        \vspace{-0.6cm}
        \newgeometry{textwidth = 5cm} % change it if you change the width of the logo
        \begin{flushright}
            {\textcolor{white}{\Date}}
        \end{flushright}
    \end{flushleft}
    \restoregeometry

    %\textcolor{white}{\text{A tagline for the company \\ 
    %spams two lines just under the logo}} 
    %\vfill
    \begin{columns}%beamer
        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        % blank
        \column{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \vspace{0.9cm}
            \textcolor{white}{\textbf{QUESTIONS?}}\\
            \vspace{0.2cm}
            \textcolor{white}{\Speaker, \SpeakerTitle}
        \end{flushleft}

    \end{columns}
    %   \section{1}
    \thispagestyle{empty}

\end{frame}
%\egroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.. Please provide the `MWE` from `\documentclass{...} ...\end{document}` as always...

Comment: Meanwhile your code works fine without any error, may the problem lies in package version, please update with the current setup, and then try...

Comment: @MadyYuvi please chk the full code now

Comment: you have an ancient package mismatch with 2012 versions, but the current version of hobsub-generic is 2016/05/16 v1.14  so it seems that you have not updated your latex system for 7 years?

Comment: the warning will not be from the `\textbf` line that you show, it will be from a package in your preamble, it is only a warning so ignore it as it will go if you update your tex system, and it is just warning you that your tex system is out of date, which is true.